# pimcore problems remote to local transfer

Tags: zend-framework, fatal-error, pimcore

I just got database + files from an "abandoned" project developed with pimcore that I need to restore.
The remote server is a LAMP environment while my PC is a WAMP one.
The site works fine remotely but when I try to open the index I get

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (Newsletter)' in D:\www\test\pimcore\lib\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248 Stack trace: #0 D:\www\test\ricordamipianella\pimcore\lib\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1 D:\www\test\pimcore\lib\Pimcore.php(216): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2 D:\www\test\index.php(19): Pimcore::run() #3 {main} thrown in D:\www\test\pimcore\lib\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line 248
```

Though I can open the control panel (at least the login page).
Since I have no knowledge of pimcore or Zend FM does anybody know how to find what's causing the error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you did a direct download of the project, make sure to check your php.ini include_path to make sure all the libraries you need are known to php.
Also look at the *index.php* file and make sure the APPLICATION_PATH constant is correct for the new enviroment. It was likely changed to reflect the remote hosts requirements.

Comment: nothing. I tried the all thing in a linux machine and still not working (SAME ERROR). I checked all the files with APPLICATION_PATH comparing the ones from a fresh working install of pimcore vs the one not working and they're the same!

Comment: is that the only controller throwing an exception or are others doing it?

Comment: in every page where the related controller is called

Comment: ok nevermind I just realized that when I copied files form the FTP server the controller folder wasn't copied because it doesn't have read permissions!